# Can you provide examples of fractal coordinates for points?

Tags: coordinate-systems, fractals

On a 1D line there is one real number needed to uniquely locate a point by coordinates.

On a 2D plane, a pair of real numbers are needed.

But what if a fractal has dimension d, between 1 and 2 ($1<d<2$), how can points on the fractal be specified with more than one, but less than 2 coordinates?

Can you provide examples of 1.xD coordinates for points?

Edit: I'm asking for a numerical example, so this is not the same question tan [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2561937/expressing-points-in-fractional-dimensions).

A point in the plane can be specified by a **single number in base 4**
if each one of the symbols represents one quadrant

```
O=0
→=1
↑=i
↗=1+i
. is a decimal separator
```

a point with coordinates 1.5+2.5i can be written ↑→.↗
meaning (the dot is a decimal separator)

$\uparrow \rightarrow . \nearrow = i*2^1+1*2^0+(1+i)*2^{-1} $

That representation system can be rewritten as pair of numbers in decimal system.

On the same way, a point on sierpinski triangle can be written in base 3 using a symbol for each of the 3 subtriangles
Any point on the fractal can be specified with arbitrary precision with a string like

←→↑←↑↑←←→.←↑←→←←↑

where each position is multiplied by a power of 2 and

```
←=0
→=1
↑=0.5+(3/4)^½i
. is a decimal separator
```

So, I expect that number to be decomposed into 1.D coordinates as a real number, and something else.

On information theory, a character may represent a non integer number of bits, and that is solved by combining multiple characters, so I expected a similar solution for expressing coordinates.

Note that on the real line, if base N is used, the characters are multiplied by power of 4, but on other dimensions, it looks like the dimension depend on the difference between the base N and the power used as positional weight.

Comment: You may want to read this:  https://medium.com/@cosinekitty/understanding-fractional-dimensions-f2ed2e4e1600.  The concept of *spatial* dimension is intuitive and we must have a natural integer number of dimensions so specify coordinates but obviously fractal dimensions mean something else entire. So short answer, Specifiying specific poins on a fractal doesn't make sense on fractional dimension.  But the real question is: in what way are these values refering to "dimensions". or .... what does that even mean???  .. That's a good question.  Good luck with it.

Comment: "Because we are stuck, let’s backtrack and consider a **different** way to define dimensions."  (emphasis mine).  Because this is a different was of considering dimension, the concept of coordinated points does not apply and can't be done.... Basically saying fractal Koch snowflake has $1< d< 2$ dimension doesn't refer to the order of independant coordinates, it refers to the  factor by which full size increase compared to increase in linear size.  which has nothing to do with coordinates.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't asked for a definition of dimension, but an example of coordinates. Any point on a Serpinsky triangle can be expressed with a single number, written in base 3, to any desired precision, same as on the real line can be written in binary or decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk of "dimensions" of fractals we mean something entirely different that the number of independant spatial coordinates to determine a point.

So the question of how to indicate a point doesn't apply or even make sense.

So what *does* the dimensions of a fractal mean?

In euclidean geometry, if we increase the radius of an $n$dimensional object in $\mathbb R^n$ by a factor of $k$, then the hyper-volume of the object increase by a factor of $k^n$.  And it is the linear increase causes an exponential growth in volume that we mean by "dimension" and that has nothing to do with coordinates.

So the area of a fraction increases in comparison to an increase in linear size by a non-integer factor.

So in *that* definition it is fractional dimensional.  But it has nothing to do with coordinates.

https://medium.com/@cosinekitty/understanding-fractional-dimensions-f2ed2e4e1600

(Sometimes we teach by analogy.  But then analogy breaks.  The *classic* example if this is $b^{n} = \underbrace{b\times b\times b......\times b}_{n\text{ times}}$.  And as just by *counting* we must have $b^{n+m} = b^nb^m$.  But what if $x\not \in \mathbb Z$? What does $b^x$ mean?  Well, knowing that $b^{x+y} = b^xb^y$ we come up with another definition based on... other stuff.  So $2^\pi = 8.824977827076287623856429604208$......  Punch it into a calculator! That's what you get.  But does that mean $2^\pi = \underbrace{2\times2\times 2\times ....}_{\pi \text{ times}} =  8.824977827076287623856429604208$????  How the heck do you multiply a number by itself $\pi$ times?  Does that make any sense?  The answer is "no" it doesn't make sense but that is not what $b^x$ means any more.  It means something else.)

Comment: multiply a number by itself π times makes sense. For example, b^2.5 means multiplying 1 by b 2 times, and by the square root of b

Comment: Multiplying by $\sqrt b$ is not multiplying by itself half a time.  It's taking a different number that when multiplied by itself is your original number and multiplying by that. If you do an action like multiplying a number by itself you can only do it a discrete positive integer number of times, you can't do it a negative number of time or a fraction number of times or an irrational number of times.  Doing something *else* and saying it is equivalent and gives you the desired results and *calling* it the impossible thing, is *not* the same thing as doing the impossible thing.

Comment: "For example, b^2.5 means multiplying 1 by b 2 times, and by the square root of b"  But that is *NOT* "multiplying $b$ by itself two and a half times".  That is finding the square root of $b^5$ and declaring $b^{\frac mn}= \sqrt[n]{b^m}$ is an entirely *new* and *DIFFERENT* definition.  For that matter definint $b^{-n}=b^n$ does not mean "multiply a negative number of times" (which makes no sense). And the argument "well if you multiply a negative number of times and then multiply a positive number of times you get back to one so multiplying a negative number of times means division" ..TBC..

Comment: .. is *not* a definition.  It is a *justification* for why division is *EQUIVALENT* to defining powers that way.  It doesn't mean you can still do the meaningless and impossible.  It means we can have a *DIFFERENT* definition that works.

Comment: Exponentiation b^x is not multiplying b by itself. It is multiplying 1 by b, x times. That's why b^0=1. 1 is multiplied zero times, and thus remains 1.

Comment: If b were multiplied by itself b^-1 would be 1, but is 1/b, because is dividing 1 by b, x times

Comment: But dividing $1$ by $b$ is *not* *multiplying* $1$ by $b$ negative $1$ times.  It is doing the *inverse* of multiplication.  ANd multiplying by $\sqrt b$ is not multiplying by $b$ half a time. It is multiplying by the inverse of squaring.  My point is the definition of $b^x$ is *no longer* multiply $1$ by $b$ $x$ times".   The definition is now something else. In fact what you are doing is redefining what "multiply by $b$ $x$ times" mean in terms of $b^x$. You are no longer saying "$b^x$ is defined as $1$ times $b$ $x$ times, but saying $1$ times $b$ $x$ times is defined as $b^x$.

Comment: On the same way, that exponentiation has to be better understood to include non integer exponents, expressing points by coordinates has to be better understood to use a non integer number of coordinates. Claiming that "the question of how to indicate a point doesn't apply or even make sense" is like claiming that "the question of how to use non integer exponents doesn't apply or even make sense"

Comment: "multiplying by b√ is not multiplying by b half a time". Yest, it is exactly that. If you do it 2 times, you multiply by b.

Comment: YOu are completely missing the point.  Those are NOT the same. They are EQUIVALENT but the are NOT the same  If doing something twice gives the same result as doing a different thing once, that is not the same thing as doing something on half times.   Going to Iceland is not going to Paris one half time.  Having 3 children isn't having 6 children one half time and $10,000$ couples havin $31,415$ children together is not $10,000$ couples each having $\pi$ children.  Multiplying by $b$ is a discrete action that cannot be done a nonnatural number of times. $b^x$ is EQUIVALENT but DIFFERENT.

Comment: You can't define the impossible and absurd by= an analogy that is equivalent and change the meaning. That an *analogous* way of thinking and coming up with an alternative way of thinking. But just like a chicken can't lay half an egg and you can't take negative square root of two breaths of air you can't multiply by $b$ $\pi$ number of times. YOu can do things that are equivalent and give the same result but they are different  And you will *never* find a textbook at the college or higher level that defines $b^x$ as "multiplying $1$ by $b$ an $x$ number of times".

Comment: That's your challenge.  Find a textbook written for *adults* and serious and rigorous mathematicians that defines $b^x$ as "multiplying $1$ times $b$ an $x$ number of times".  You will find some may define $b^n$ that way for integers but *all* of them *extend* and replace the definition.

Answer (score 0):

Such a coordinate system won't exist.  I draw an analogy with polynomials.  A linear function can be specified by two reals and a quadratic can be specified by three.  Yet when we attempt to find a polynomial to represent a function like $ x^{1.5} $, you do not get an expression with 1.5 coefficients, but infinitely many.  The series expansion is infinite.

Similarly, it would take infinite information to specify a point on the Sierpinski triangle.  So there is something fundamentally different about fractional-dimensional spaces versus integral dimensional spaces, just as polynomials are different from functions involving fractional powers of $ x $.

Comment: It takes infinite information to express a point like (x,y)=(e,pi), but that does not means that a coordinate system cannot exist.

Answer (score -1):

You're confusing the *topological* dimension of an embedding with the *intrinsic* dimension.  You need as many (integer) coordinates as the topological dimension.

Comment: The question here isn't even really describing a topological notion of dimension---it is describing a vector-space-flavoured notion of dimension.

Comment: "vector-space-flavoured notion of dimension" doesn't make sense.  Please cite a book or paper or website which you think explains that.

Comment: I am sorry that you object to an informal description of mathematics.  The dimension of a vector space is the cardinality of a basis for that vector space.  This corresponds to the number of coordinates which are needed to specify a point.  This is the intuition described in the question.  Topological notions of dimension typically refer to properties of covers of the space by open sets (the Lebesgue dimension), or inductive notions related to the boundaries of open sets (e.g. the small and large inductive dimensions).

Comment: For the dimension of a vector space, please refer to any introductory text on abstract algebra, e.g Hungerford or Dummit & Foote.  Topological notions of dimension are a little more specialized---my goto is Robinson's *Dimensions, Embeddings, and Attractors*, though this is a very specialized text.  I am sure that topologists have more general references, but that isn't my area of expertise.

Comment: @XanderHenderson:  As you certainly know, a vector space must have a notion of addition and multiplication of its core entities (vectors), and several axioms, such as *associativity*, *commutativity*, *identity element*, *inverse*, *distributivity*,... none of which seem relevant to the question as posed.  However, topological dimension (how many components are needed to specify a point in the set) seems precisely what is in order.

Comment: The original asker speaks of Euclidean space and a coordinatization.  This is implicitly invoking notions from vector spaces.  How do you specify the coordinates or components of a point in a general topological setting?

Comment: Turning the question back on you, *which* topological notion of dimension are you referring to in your answer?  There are several...

Comment: Indeed.  Lebesque covering dimension is the most commonly invoked (at least from my readings), leading to $n$-dimensional Euclidean space as having topological dimension $n$.